# RNN model for predicting room temperatures

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, predictive-models, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently doing a project in Machine Learning where I am trying to predict the temperature of a room in future.

I have a 1-year dataset of a house with 12 rooms. Data is collected at 10 min interval. Hence, 6 points at every 1 hr interval.
The dataset contains the following features -

- Outdoor Temperature [degC]
- Global solar radiation [W/m2]
- Rain Status  [Yes/No]
- Outdoor Wind Speed [m/s]
- Outdoor Wind Direction [deg]
- Individual Room Temperature of all the room [degC]
- Individual Occupancy information for all the rooms [Yes/No]
- Individual Electricity consumption of all the rooms [W]
- Individual Light power consumption of all the rooms [W]

I plan to predict the Room Temperature of 1 Specific Room, using input features (total - 18 features)

- Outdoor Temperature
- Global Solar radiation
- Outdoor Wind Speed
- Outdoor Wind Direction
- Specific room Occupancy
- Specific room Electricity consumption
- Specific room Light power
- Room temperature of all other 11 rooms

I am planning to train an RNN model to predict the temperature of the specific room.

Now, in the house, we also have a floor heating system, that will heat the room to achieve a setpoint temperature.
The idea with the model is to guide the floor heating system to make it act upon the future room temperature in the room.

Now my doubt is if a model trained on data collected without floor heating, can also predict in presence of floor heating?
I am hoping that the model will learn the relation between the different input features with room temperature.
Hence, even if I change the room temperature, the model will still be able to predict.

Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a try. Since we don't use all samples as timesteps in RNN, we learn "patterns" from history and make prediction based on recent timesteps. The predition won't be really bad even we use naive history average method, not to speak of RNN. 
I don't know whether the pattern will change after you adopt the new heating system, if so, the last year's data is somehow useless  no matter what method you use. From my experience, you can try to train a model to predict and iterate its version if you have new system's data to have better performance.

Comment: What I was hoping that the model will learn the relationship between all the input features and the room temperature. So even if the room temperature is changed, because the model learned the relationship, I was hoping that it will still be able to predict. But ya, as you said, I will also try.